# How to make fixed header at the top of the page by Chakra UI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

How to make header menu only right side?

[image]

[image]

I use Next.js and Chakra UI and Code this below.

```
<DashboardLayout>
```

means left side window.

```
<EditSubHeader>
```

means header menu.

```
   return (
    <DashboardLayout>
      <Box w="100%">
        <Box position="fixed" right="0" zIndex="999">
          <EditSubHeader
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            backLink={pagesPath.admin.products.$url()}
            isLoading={creatingProduct}
          />
        </Box>
        <Box px={12}>
          <Heading mt={10}>商品登録</Heading>
          <Box bg={alias.background.white} px={6} pt={12} pb={16}>
          .
          .
          .
          .
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </DashboardLayout>
  );
```